# Fading an Image - C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image, fade

I don't quite understand why it is so complicated as in a standard windows form the code below works just fine. But anyway.

I am trying to just fade an image in, and then fade it back out. At the moment I can't even get it to fade in, I feel pretty dumb because I'm sure there is something I am doing wrong. The for loop works but the image opacity does not change until it gets to 99 and then it suddenly changes. Please help because this is driving me mad.

```
namespace WpfApplication2
{
   /// <summary>
   /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
   /// </summary>
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
   {
      public MainWindow()
      {
            InitializeComponent();
      }

      private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         for (int i = 1; i <+ 100; i++)
         {
            Logo.Opacity = i;
            label1.Content = i;                       
         }
      }

      private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
      {
         System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
         dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
         dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 10);
         dispatcherTimer.Start();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Better use a DoubleAnimation for the Opacity property.

Comment: I'd be a liar if I said I knew what that is. I will look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know exactly what behaviour you want to get, but in WPF you should use animations. Probably you have to adapt the parameters:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation
    {
        From = 0,
        To = 1,
        Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)),
        AutoReverse = true
    };
    Logo.BeginAnimation(OpacityProperty, da);
}
```

Comment: DoubleAnimation is not showing as being valid. Do I need to add an extra using statement?

Comment: `using System.Windows.Media.Animation;`

Comment: Cheers :) that works amazingly. Is there a MS reference for all of the available params? I'd quite like it to fade in, stay for a bit, then just go :)

Comment: There's plenty of documentation. Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752312%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.doubleanimation%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and all the subchapters. But a quick hack for what you wanted: set the `To`-parameter to let's say 3 and increase the `Duration`. While the animation sets invalid values greater than 1 the real value will stay at 1.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way you can perform action after the animation has finished? i.e another animation (such as moving image)

Comment: Create a second animation object and set the `BeginTime` property to delay the start. Call again BeginAnimation with the respective DependencyProperty and the new animation object just after the first BeginAnimation. There is not only a `DoubleAnimation` class but many others to animate other value types than double. Just get inspired by the documentation. :-)

Comment: Ok, thanks! :) I've been playing around with it a little bit, got the fade working perfectly, is it possible to use animations to make something like i counter? I gave it a go doing this: `c               DoubleAnimation Count = new DoubleAnimation
                {
                    From = 1,
                    To = 100,
                    Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)),
                    AutoReverse = false,
                };
                txtCounter.BeginAnimation(ContentProperty, Count);`

Comment: @BillyKindell You shouldn't be asking one question after the other in comments here. Please take the time to read MSDN and other online documentation about animations (there is plenty). It may also be helpful to read a book about WPF, e.g. *WPF Unleashed* by Adam Nathan. And yes, there is a `Completed` event that you can use to perform actions when an animation has completed.

Comment: As I have to leave now a last answer: look (or google) for `StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames` and `StringKeyFrameCollection`. Of course it's a little bit more complicated because you can't just interpolate between two string. Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

Opacity is `double` with 0.0 - 1.0 range. So the loop should be something like this.

```
for (double i = 0.0; i <= 1.0; i+=0.01)
{
    Logo.Opacity = i;
    label1.Content = i;
}
```

But as Clemens pointed out it also won't work. You're doing entire loop in one short burst. You should do one increment per timer tick:

```
double CurrentOpacity = 0.0;
private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CurrentOpacity += 0.01;
    if(CurrentOpacity <= 1.0)
    {
        Logo.Opacity = CurrentOpacity;
        label1.Content =CurrentOpacity;
    }
    else
    {
        dispatcherTimer.Stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: This still blocks the UI thread, and will hence not have any visual effect except that the opacity is finally 1.0.

Comment: @Clemens Right, I focussed on the Opacity range so much I totally missed the other problem, brb